# how to loop through the table and echoing out the number for each loop

Tags: php

I can manage to use the while loop to display the information into a table but how would I add a number for each main information to make it more organise? Would I need to add a for loop here or can this be done using just the while loop?

I have tried to add a for loop and surrounded it with double quotes but got a parse error of string

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   for($x=1; $x<=$resultCheck; $x++) {
      echo "<tr><th>$x Clinic Name:</th><td>$row['clinic_name']</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Clinic Address:</th><td>$row['clinic_address']</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Clinic Number:</th><td>$row['clinic_number']</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Which of the following are you?</th><td>$row['type_of_profession']</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Services:</th><td>$row['services']</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Recommended Doctors:</th><td>$row['doctors']</td></tr>";                  
   }
}
```

I can get it to work with the following code but is there an easier way to use double quotes?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                           for($x=1; $x<=$resultCheck; $x++) {
                         echo '<tr><th>'.$x.'Clinic Name:</th><td>'.$row['clinic_name'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Clinic Address:</th><td>'.$row['clinic_address'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Clinic Number:</th><td>'.$row['clinic_number'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Which of the following are you?</th><td>'.$row['type_of_profession'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Services:</th><td>'.$row['services'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Recommended Doctors:</th><td>'.$row['doctors'].'</td></tr>';
```

I tried something like while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $row<=$resultCheck' $row++)

but it doesn't like the ; used between each variable

Comment: Remove the for loop, do it all in the while loop. Create a variable that you increment for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Qirel already mentioned you just need to add a counter variable that you increment for each iteration of your outer loop:

```
$rowNumber = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rowNumber++;
  echo "<tr><th>$rowNumber  Clinic Name:</th><td>$row['clinic_name']</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Clinic Address:</th><td>$row['clinic_address']</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Clinic Number:</th><td>$row['clinic_number']</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Which of the following are you?</th><td>$row['type_of_profession']</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Services:</th><td>$row['services']</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Recommended Doctors:</th><td>$row['doctors']</td></tr>";                  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it! Why is it better to do this in a while loop than a for loop?

Comment: The point is: you only need a single loop, your original outer `while` loop, not two loops, one inside the other. For that single loop a ``for`` loop does not make much sense, since you'd have to invest effort into first fetching the number of rows to have a termination condition for your loop. Using a `while` loop is more common for the task of fetching rows from a sql result set and works just fine here.